# Include RPCClient in Docker container

Tags: corda

I'm currently deploying nodes on Azure VMS using Docker. First I'm building the nodes and bootstrapping using the corda network bootstrapper:

`java -jar corda-tools-network-bootstrapper-4.3.jar --dir .`

Here is my partA_node.conf

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="host.docker.internal:10004"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10005"
    adminAddress="localhost:10006"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
sshd {
    port = 10007
}
```

Next I'm building the Docker images:

`docker-compose build`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM corda/corda-zulu-java1.8-4.3:latest
COPY ./PartyA /etc/corda
COPY ./PartyA/certificates /opt/corda/certificates
COPY ./PartyA/cordapps /opt/corda/cordapps
COPY ./PartyA/additional-node-infos /opt/corda/additional-node-infos
COPY ./PartyA/network-parameters /opt/corda/network-parameters
EXPOSE 10004 10005 10006 10007
```

I can build the Docker containers and deploy the nodes without any issues. So far so good.

Next I need to have a RPC client communicating with the node to start flows and query the vault. With local development I can use the template RPC client just fine but I have no idea how to include the RPC client in the docker image, as there is no jar file I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which RPC Client you're using locally, but I often find the [Standalone Shell](https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/corda/net/corda/corda-shell) useful.

[Shell Docs](https://docs.corda.net/shell.html?highlight=shell#standalone-shell-via-ssh)

Also it looks like you can just ssh directly to the node at port `10007` so you don't necessarily need the client.  Depending, of course, on your use case.